# C++ issue with standard library

Tags: c++, class, std

I'am making this post because i have for the first time of my life an incomprehensible error from visual studio community 2017 :

I simply can't use others members of std then "nullptr_t" in all my classes except in the main.cpp .... 
The auto-completion of visual only suggest me "nullptr_t" when I write "std::" except in the main.cpp. It's incomprehensible.

main.cpp code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Point class code :

```
#pragma once


class Point
{

private:
    float _x;
    float _y;

public:
    Point();
    Point(float x, float y);
    Point(const Point& p);
    ~Point();

    float getx() { return _x; }
    float gety() { return _y; }

    void setx(float x) { _x = x; }
    void sety(float y) { _y = y; }
};
```

/************************************************************************/

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Point.h"


Point::Point()
{
    _x = 0.0;
    _y = 0.0;
}

Point::Point(float x, float y)
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
}

Point::Point(const Point& p)
{
    _x = p._x;
    _y = p._y;
}

Point::~Point()
{
}
```

Hexagon class :

```
#pragma once


class Hexagon
{

private:
    Point _center;
    float _diameter;


public:
    Hexagon();
    Hexagon(Point center, float diameter);
    ~Hexagon();
};
```

/***********************************************************************/

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Hexagon.h"
#include "Point.h"


Hexagon::Hexagon() : _center()
{
    _diameter = 10;
}

Hexagon::Hexagon(Point center, float diameter) : _center(center)
{
    _diameter = diameter;
}

Hexagon::~Hexagon()
{
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] emphasis on __Minimal__.

Comment: What headers have you included that you'd expect to expose any `std::` functions/classes?

Comment: Can you build it? You should not always trust the autocompletion. Maybe something in your config is disabled

Comment: Close your project. Delete all the temporary files associated with your project. Reopen project. Problem gone (hopefully). Sometimes VC++ gets its knickers in a twist.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the iostream library or add this line of code where you need it to the includes.

```
#include<iostream>
```